# angular 1.5 components and es6 modules

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and I am trying to use the new component helper in angular 1.5.

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Github Invoicing</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">

  <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl as ctrl">
    <log-in/>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.js file looks like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import logIn from './components/logIn';

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
});
```

My logIn.js file looks like this

```
import angular from 'angular';

angular.module('app')
  .component('logIn', {
    template: function($element, $attrs) {
      return [
        '<div>Content</div>'
      ].join('');
    }
  });
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

This is obviously because the app has not been created when the import statement for `logIn.js` executes from `app.js` runs.

If this was react or ember, I would be exporting the component somehow but as I'm new to angular, I don't really know what to do.

The only way I can get this to work is define `logIn.js` like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

const logIn = {
  template: function($element, $attrs) {
    return [
      '<div>Content</div>'
    ].join('');
  }
};

export default logIn;
```

And then create the component in `app.js`:

import angular from 'angular';

```
import logIn from './components/logIn';

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  }).component('logIn', logIn);
```

This feels wrong.

Comment: Can you try with angular.module('app') in logIn.js. angular.module('app', []) is for declaration. We declare once usually.

Comment: @NagaSandeep I think you are on to something because when I remove the empty array I get the error:

Module 'app' is not available

I think it is because the import statement is ran before the module code.  NOt sure what to do about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create another module e.x. component

```
import angular from 'angular'

    angular.module('component',[])
      .component('logIn', {
        template: function($element, $attrs) {
          return [
            '<div>Content</div>'
          ].join('');
        }
      });
```

and your app will be depended on this module

```
import angular from 'angular';
import logIn from './components/logIn';

angular.module('app', ['component'])
  .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
});
```